# Open instagram ad link in default mobile browser

Tags: mobile, e-commerce, instagram, ads

We are creating Instagram ad for the product (from ads manager panel) . It contains the link to the webpage , where one of the steps is that you need to upload the picture.

Problem here is that ad is opened in some kind of "instagram" browser, not in like chrome or safari. And when user tries to upload the image, the process crashes.

Is it possible to force open this ad in default browser?

Comment: Anyone figured this out? We're encountering processes that don't work when inside the "instagram browser".

Comment: same here.. couldnt figure it out..

Answer (score -1):

About thirty seconds after I initiated the bounty, I found the solution.  So simple it was difficult...

Instead of, e.g.: https://www.instagram.com/p/LetTerS -- simply replace with https://m.instagram.com/p/LeTtErS/

When opened on desktop, Chrome (tested) quickly resolves back to "www." - the phone opens the link in a browser properly (tested on Nexus 5X, Samsung Something).

Comment: To clarify OP's question, s/he is asking if it is possible to "break out" of the Instagram Webview browser from an IG ad.